# C# Multi Language SearchedLocation not true

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a project and I'm trying to add language support to this project.

First I tried this event by creating a new project and it worked flawlessly. After integrating the codes into my actual project, unfortunately it should come as

```
SearchedLocation = "ProjectName".Resources.Controllers.PostsController
```

but it comes as

```
"ProjectName".Resources.Project_Name.Controllers.PostsController"
```

I am using Docker in the project.Has anyone encountered such a problem before?

My `Program.cs` code:

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
var app = builder.Build();

var supportedCultures = new[] { "en-US", "ar" };
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
options
.AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
.AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
.SetDefaultCulture("en-US")
.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
{
    return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult("en-gb"));
}))
);
```

Controller:

```
public class PostsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<PostsController> _stringLocalizer;

    public PostsController(IStringLocalizer<PostsController> stringLocalizer)
    {
        _stringLocalizer = stringLocalizer;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("PostsControllerResource")]
    public IActionResult GetUsingPostsControllerResource()
    {
        var article = _stringLocalizer["Article"];
        var postName = _stringLocalizer.GetString("Welcome").Value ?? "";

        return Ok(new { PostType = article.Value, PostName = postName });
    }
}
```

Folder structure

[image]

Comment: Could you please share the whole screen shot for the solution?

Comment: @BrandoZhang problem solved after changing project name thank you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I suggest you could generate a reply and mark it as answer so that other folks will find the solution more easily.